# How to make my website fit on all screen resolutions

Tags: html, css

I have researched this but none of the code works. I need to know how to make a website fit on any screen resolution.

Comment: show us the code you've tried, it looks you just want someone to write code for you if you don't

Comment: have you googled it before posting your question?

Comment: How much time have you spent researching? Responsive web development is a very broad subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called `responsive design` and is exactly what Twitter Bootstrap was invented for.

I do not usually reference W3Schools, but [their bootstap tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/) is worth doing.

The basis of Bootstrap is their `grid system`. Learn that (about 1 hr for tutorial and one hour for experimentation), and you will have solved most of your responsive design issues.

Then, you should experiment with css @media queries. Bootstrap uses them, and so should you *(for fine-tuning results on different sized displays).*

To get started with Bootstrap, all you need is to include the appropriate libraries into the head part of your web pages. Since Bootstrap is built on jQuery, you must also include the jQuery library. So, the `<head>` section of your web pages should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Your Domain</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="your site description goes here" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="search, keywords, go, here" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/your_favicon.png?v=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```